# Firefox Add-on RESTclient - How to input POST parameters?

Tags: rest, post, firefox-addon

I've installed Firefox RESTclient add-on but , I'm having hard time figuring out how to pass POST parameters. Is there a specific format to do this? Or is there any other tool which can be used to debug an REST API on Mac OS X ?

Comment: BTW, I like to use `Poster` (another add-on of FF).

Answer (score 213, accepted):

If you want to submit a POST request

1. You have to set the “**request header**” section of the Firefox plugin to have a “**name**” = “**`Content-Type`**” and “**value**” = “**`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**”
2. Now, you are able to submit parameter like “`name=mynamehere&title=TA`” in the “request body” text area field

Comment: This gets you part of the way. If you're using the Parameters tab, you have to switch back to Content to Send and press the "Body from Parameters" button

Comment: jsut extending the answer.if you are sending the parameters then at your controller also you should mention consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in request mapping.hope this will give idea from the controller side aswell.

Answer (score 47):

Here is a step by step guide (I think this should come pre-loaded with the add-on):

1. In the top menu of RESTClient -> Headers -> Custom Header
2. In the pop-up box, enter **Name**: `Content-Type` and **Value**: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Check the "Save to favorite" box and click Okay.
   Now you will see a "Headers" section with your newly added data.
4. Then in the Body section, you can enter your data to post like:

   ```
   username=test&name=Firstname+Lastname
   ```
5. Whenever you want to make a post request, from the Headers main menu, select the `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` item that you added and it should work.

Answer (score 11):

You can send the parameters in the URL of the POST request itself.

Example URL:

```
localhost:8080/abc/getDetails?paramter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

Once you copy such type of URL in Firefox REST client make a POST call to the server you want

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Are you sure it'll work for a POST ? it seems this is a GET call.

Comment: Yes, it should work for a POST request. I have used it. You can make a POST call with such URLs.

Comment: its not a POST, I have a wireshark record to show:

POST /restService/usersPost/test?param1=hallo HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: null
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: We should not ssupply data in url when using post that is wrong way doing that.

Comment: it cannot be exposed the parameters in URL for post,it is not recommended.

Comment: I think this needs to be handled with something for example like `[FromUri]` in Asp.Net ;).

Answer (score 5):

Request header needs to be set as per below image.[image: add request header]

request body can be passed as json string in text area.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried the methods mentioned in some other answers, but they look like workarounds to me. Using Firefox Add-on RESTclient to send HTTP POST requests with parameters is not straightforward in my opinion, at least for the version I'm currently using, 2.0.1.

Instead, try using other free open source tools, such as Apache JMeter. It is simple and straightforward (see the screenshot as below)

[image]