# How to test POST calls?

Tags: c#, post, soap

What is the easiest way (i.e.  requiring writing as little code as humanly possible) to make a POST call given that we know a server, service and parameter list (got from WSDL file)?

Worst case scenario, I'll have to code such a facility myself.
Best case scenario, there's a free service on-line doing that already.

Yes, I've googled but apparently there isn't such a site **or** I such at googling. I'd like to use it for for call to SOAP services during my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firefox plugins - Postman and Rest client

Refer [Firefox Add-on RESTclient - How to input POST parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132794/firefox-add-on-restclient-how-to-input-post-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is quite an awesome little tool:

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

There is a video on Pluralsight that explains its use and you will find it becoming a regular part of your tool-set:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#debugging