# Is this the correct format of POST body?

Tags: python, django, http-post

I am POST-ing to a view in Django. The POST body contains data in the following format :

```
{
    'Service' : 'API'
}
```

and I am doing this in my view :

```
args = request.POST
service = args.get('Service', '').strip()
```

But `service` comes out as `''`

I used pdb and `request.POST` is like this :

```
<QueryDict: {u"{\n    'Service' : 'API'\n}": [u'']}>
```

Thats the reason `service` becomes `''` because it has become a dict-in-a-dict. I want to know is this supposed to happen? What is the `[u'']`. From where does it get added in to the body? If it is something that should happen, how do I parse the body to get out `Service`?

Comment: is that the entire POST dict ? To get a dict, you can do `request.POST.copy()` to get the exact post dictionary. Also, there is something else messing the code up. Like `{\n    'Service' : 'API'\n}` is being evaluated as the key

Comment: How are you posting the info to the view? Through a template? Can you illustrate it a little?

Comment: @karthikryes. like there are other fields which I am not posting. So how should I get rid of the `\n` from the request.POST dict? I mean when POST-ing  the `\n is going to be included any way right?`

Comment: well.. It should not, but apparently some formatting or some kind of code is messing the POST. can you post your HTML, and view ? Also the entire POST object?

Comment: @PauloBu Ultimately its going to be a client POST-ing the data. So at the moment I am using RESTClient for Fireox.

Comment: Still, it seems to be something wrong when you POST the info. You'll have to show us.

Comment: @karthikr Thats the entire POST object at the moment.

Comment: @PauloBu What do you want me to show?

Comment: If you are using the Restclient, you are probably using the wrong format to send the key value pairs. Please check that

Comment: @karthikr whats the correct format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132794/firefox-add-on-restclient-how-to-input-post-parameters

Comment: @karthikr I changed the format as suggested in the answer.
And the `args` is `<QueryDict: {u"{\n    'Service' : 'API'\n}": [u'']}>` but still `Service` is `''`

Comment: why is the key `{\n 'Service' : 'API'\n}` ? Are you missing some `"` or `'` somewhere?

Comment: @karthikr the key is 'Service'

Comment: i know that, but the dict for `request.POST` is taking the key as `{\n 'Service' : 'API'\n}` which is the problem

Comment: @karthikr I can't really figure it out why. My command is : `service = args.get('Service', '')`

Comment: `<QueryDict: {u'Status': [u'NORMAL"\n'], u'"Service': [u'API']}>`

Theres a `"` after `NORMAL` and just before `Service` I wonder if its casing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're posting a string like that (common for things like JSON-RPC), vs using a known format (like `multipart/form-data`), you can use this (in your view):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    body = request.body  # This is your string
    data = json.loads(body)
    service = data['Service']
```

This is predicated on your front-end code posting valid JSON data back. Otherwise, you'll be left to your own devices to decode something less standard (your example uses single quotes, for instance - not valid JSON). Encode a JavaScript object into JSON using `JSON.stringify(my_obj)`, then post that value.

Comment: I stopped using REST Client. Wrote a script using requests module to post the data. Its working fine now. :)

Comment: Excellent, nice idea - requests is a terrific library.