# How to pass --data "{'myuid':'testuser1'}" while testing Rest API with the RestClient

Tags: json, api, rest-client, advanced-rest-client

I am testing the following API in RestClient but I am not getting the response because I don't know how to pass the --data "{'myuid':'testuser1'}".

```
curl -k -v -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt 
     -X POST 
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"
     --data "{'myuid':'testuser1'}"
     "https://<isam address>/mgaapi/sps/apiauthsvc?PolicyId=urn:ibm:security:authentication:asf:mytotp"
```

I have attached the screenshot as well.

How should I correctly pass the --data "{'myuid':'testuser1'}" in the RestClient to get response from the server?

[RestAPI Testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0QN1.jpg)

Comment: little bit proper googling would yield you desired result.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132794/firefox-add-on-restclient-how-to-input-post-parameters

Comment: I have set the **Content-Type** and **value** = **application/json** in request header. Is there any special format for passing the --data "{'myuid':'testuser1'}" in the request body for Content-Type=application/json?

Comment: https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/display/sciencebase/Using+RESTClient+for+Firefox
check this and see where are you doing wrong. one more thing shouldn't the key values be in double quotes rather than single?

Comment: I answered it try and tell if it worked or not

Comment: Yes I have now tried with **{"myuid":"testuser1"}** in request body and successfully received the response.

Comment: then accept the answer, please. here people ask question and get answers whichever answer solves their problem they accept as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out with little (proper and required) formatting :

```
curl -k -v -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt 
     -X POST
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
     -H "Accept: application/json"
     --data '{"myuid":"testuser1"}'
     https://<aa>/mgaapi/sps/apiauthsvc?PolicyId=urn:ibm:security:authentication:asf:mytotp
```

Format is this:
**`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}' URL`**