# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm running into a trouble since a few days. I'm learning the MEAN stack, but during creation of a user on mongo using mongoose schema, I have this problem :

> (node:93337) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required.

Here's my code :

The server part :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Wisebatt', err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Not connected to db ${err}`)
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to db')
  }
})
```

...

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User();
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.save();
    res.send('User created');
});
```

The UserSchema :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Here are the add-ons I'm using :

- Express,
- Nodemon,
- Morgan,
- Body Parser,
- Mongo (With mongod running & Mongoose)

Comment: can you post the part where you setup the database (mongodb) on the server? I'm guessing you haven't got the right credentials or database.

Comment: Sure, here it is : ``mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Wisebatt', (err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(`Not connected to db ${err}`);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to db');
    }
});``

Comment: You're not setting a username/password to connect to MongoDB with your current DSN

Comment: can you console log req.body.username ? it might be undefined.

Comment: `console.log(req.body)`. The error is from Mongoose validation of your schema. It means that there is no value assigned to the `username` or `password` fields. This is because they have been given `null` values because there is no such properties in `req.body`. You likely have something wrong with the request or body parser setup. Nothing to do with the connection.

Comment: clearly something is failing, not sure what because I'm not that familiar with mongoose - however, your code seems to be written as if `.save` is **synchronous** ... hint: it isn't, and that's where the unhandled rejection warning comes from

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yeah, I'm not setting any username/password, but It's supposed to work because I managed to send a post request with an empty object

Comment: @MattPengelly Yeah it's undefined

Comment: if `req.body` is undefined, then the problem could be (most likely) in the client code that you've failed to show - please show your client side code

Comment: seriously, you need to show your client side code as that is the likely place you've made one error (you still have an error in this code though, because you treat `.save` as being synchronous

Comment: By the client code, you mean the post request I sent to my server ?

Comment: yes ... what is **sending** the `POST` request - that's the *client* to your *server*

Comment: @JaromandaX see the other comment thread. he mentioned using a REST client and we touched on that for a bit. Hes still having issues though im guessing its still related to the REST Client.

Comment: that's irrelevant @MattPengelly, can't help fix his issue if he doesn't show the code that most likely has the issue

Comment: I'm sending the POST request with a firefox addon called RESTClient, I added the Content-Type Headers and the body request looks good for me : ``{
'username': 'Hello',
'password': 'Nope',
'email': 'a@a.fr'
}``

Comment: It's not irrelevant. It's just not particularly helpful because he can't easily show his request object. It's completely relevant.

Comment: I meant the comment is irrelevant (in a way) because the OP needs to show the code in the **question** ...

Comment: @YanisBendahmane - in your browser, check the *developer* tools network tab, to see what the browser is sending in that `POST` request

Comment: and what code interprets `{ 'username': 'Hello', 'password': 'Nope', 'email': 'a@a.fr' }` as being a username, password and email? - that's just a string

Comment: Here's what's sent by my browser : `'email': '?' 
'password': 'Hey', 
'username': 'Oui', 
{ 
}`

Comment: And yeah... The two lasts are really weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem...

Clearly, the problem is due to one of these two :

- The browser used,
- The extension sending the POST request

Surprise, I tried with Postman, and the request successfully work. So all the code was great, the problem came from one of the two up.

So, that learned me a thing. If it's not your code, It's the software you're using that can destroy all you have done

Comment: Did you end up using the Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded like i mentioned? because if so it'd be nice to get an upvote or marked as answer. Your answer here isn't really providing any information to the next user that has this problem

Comment: Yeah, I added it, I will upvote, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your express code prior to your routes. This is a middleware that will setup the req.body object when you send requests to the backend. (you'll also need to npm install --save body-parser)

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

if youre using a rest client. make sure that you have a request header such as:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: can you show how you're sending the request? via HTML? Postman? etc? post the code if there is some or mention how if using postman.

Comment: i suspect the problem is likely due to how the backend request is being made.

Comment: I'm sending it via RESTClient cuz' I'm using Firefox and there is no postman on it
Here is the body request :
`{
    'username': 'StringData',
    'password': 'SomePassword',
    'email': 'random@mail.com'
}`

Comment: if youre using a rest client. make sure that you have a request header like this. 

Content-Type set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`
Is that this ?

Comment: you need both the above line of code AND Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

in the headers.. if youre using a REST client. I've had this issue before.

Comment: Even if I add this to my REST client, still the same problem :(

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132794/firefox-add-on-restclient-how-to-input-post-parameters

you may not be doing the setup correctly.

Comment: Even by adding the headers, still having the same trouble. Still doesn't uderstand why

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expressJS  then make sure that you have to add this lines.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Specially this one,

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // this is for app.post to submit route..
```

in the `app.js` or `index.js`